# What is $\mathcal{M}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I came across  $\mathcal{M}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ in my exercise book on algebra, but there was no mention of it in the lesson. How is it defined or what should I reference to find a definition.
It doesn't look like the usual $\,\!M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Without further context, I would say it is just the same as $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two things should be the same. Some authors use $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and  others use the unadorned $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, but they both mean $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Alright. The problem is that I had to skip a couple of lessons and so I wondered if that was something different from $\!M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Doubtful. It should be the same thing.